# Interactive objects in Unity VR with OnOver and OnOut (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interactive, virtual-reality, oculus

[Printscreen from Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDLnB.jpg)
I'm creating a VR-app in Unity for Oculus Go. 
I want to show some text over a sprite while the laser pointer hovers over certain game objects and disappear when its not. I'm trying to do this by creating an array that is supposed to show the specific game objects components (textmesh + sprite) when the laser pointer hovers over that specific object. At this stage, it's only the last objects text+sprite in the list that shows, regardless of which game object the laser pointer is hovering over.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using VRStandardAssets.Utils;

public class ObjectManager : MonoBehaviour
{

[SerializeField] VRInteractiveItem[] InteractiveObjects;
[SerializeField] Transform reticleTransform;

private VRInteractiveItem currentObject;

void Start()
{

    foreach (VRInteractiveItem t in InteractiveObjects)
    {

        foreach (MeshRenderer renderer in t.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>())
        {
            renderer.enabled = false;
        }


        foreach (SpriteRenderer renderer in t.GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>())
        {
            renderer.enabled = false;
        }
    }

}


void OnEnable()
{
    foreach (VRInteractiveItem t in InteractiveObjects)
    {
        currentObject = t;
        currentObject.OnOver += Popup;
    }
}


void Popup()
{
        foreach (MeshRenderer renderer in currentObject.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>())
        {
            renderer.enabled = true;
        }

        foreach (SpriteRenderer renderer in currentObject.GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>())
        {
            renderer.enabled = true;
        }

        currentObject.OnOut += Popdown;
}


void Popdown()
{ 
        foreach (MeshRenderer renderer in currentObject.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>())
        {
            renderer.enabled = false;
        }

        foreach (SpriteRenderer renderer in currentObject.GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>())
        {
            renderer.enabled = false;
        }

}

}
```

How do I let the laser pointer know which specific game object I'm interacting with and make it only show that object's components? I've tried finding a solution with ID's but haven't gotten it to work in VR.

Comment: Did you see https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality/interaction-vr ? I'ld say the better solution would be to let every component handle it themselves instead of trying to do it all from one manager component.

Comment: Yeah I’ve looked at it. I’m starting to think that tol - I’ve just been struggling with trying to get this solution to work for so long so I thought I’d see if anyone else could tell if I’m missing something.

Comment: The problem is the callback doesn't get the information on which object it was called ... so it would be better to have the callback on the object itself so you don't have to "know" on which one it was called.

Answer (score 0):

As said before I would actually rather suggest to let every `VRInteractiveItem` handle the `OnOver` itself than doing it all from one manager component.

---

A thing you could do however (though I would not recommend), is using lambda expressions with a `for` loop instead of `foreach` as callbacks instead of methods like

```
void OnEnable()
{
    for(var i= 0; i < InteractiveObjects.Length; i++)
    {
        var index = i;
        InteractiveObjects[index].OnOver += () => {
            foreach (MeshRenderer renderer in InteractiveObjects[index].GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>())
            {
                renderer.enabled = true;
            }

            foreach (SpriteRenderer renderer in InteractiveObjects[index].GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>())
            {
                renderer.enabled = true;
            }

            InteractiveObjects[index].OnOut += () => {
                foreach (MeshRenderer renderer in InteractiveObjects[index].GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>())
                {
                    renderer.enabled = false;
                }

                foreach (SpriteRenderer renderer in InteractiveObjects[index].GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>())
                {
                    renderer.enabled = false;
                }
            };
        };
    }
}
```

A problem with that is that you can not remove those callbacks (`InteractiveObjects[index].OnOut -= XYZ`) as you could do with methods.

So you actually should not add `InteractiveObjects[index].OnOut +=` everytime the object is hovered because you might end up with mutliple executions of the disabling code. You might rather add it in `OnEnable` as well like

```
void OnEnable()
{
    for(var i= 0; i < InteractiveObjects.Length; i++)
    {
        var index = i;
        InteractiveObjects[index].OnOver += () => {
            foreach (MeshRenderer renderer in InteractiveObjects[index].GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>())
            {
                renderer.enabled = true;
            }

            foreach (SpriteRenderer renderer in InteractiveObjects[index].GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>())
            {
                renderer.enabled = true;
            }
        };

        InteractiveObjects[index].OnOut += () => {
            foreach (MeshRenderer renderer in InteractiveObjects[index].GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>())
            {
                renderer.enabled = false;
            }

            foreach (SpriteRenderer renderer in InteractiveObjects[index].GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>())
            {
                renderer.enabled = false;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! I went with letting every component handle the script by themselves though, it seemed like the easiest way out.